# In equation reference of bookdown, \tag cannot be used with (\#eq:label)

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

## Problem

I am writing a paper using bookdown. I want to give one equation a special name (say "R"), and refer to it later. However, the equation cannot be rendered in `html` format.

```
\begin{equation}
    \tag{$\mathrm{R}$}
    V_1 \ge \hat{U}_1 \text{ with the equality if and only if }x =1
    (\#eq:R)    
\end{equation}
```

## Failed attempts

I tried to (i) put `\tag` at different places in the equation environment and (ii) cancel the indent. But all failed. It seems that I have used two tag commands as in the image below:

[image: gitbook output]

Remark: the pdf output works with no problem.

[image: PDF output]

## Information of `bookdown`

`xfun::session_info('bookdown')`

```
> R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17134), RStudio 1.2.1335
> 
> Locale:
>   LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936 
>   LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936   
>   LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936
>   LC_NUMERIC=C                              
>   LC_TIME=Chinese (Simplified)_China.936    
> 
> Package version:
>   base64enc_0.1.3 bookdown_0.9    digest_0.6.18   evaluate_0.13  
>   glue_1.3.1      graphics_3.5.2  grDevices_3.5.2 highr_0.8      
>   htmltools_0.3.6 jsonlite_1.6    knitr_1.22      magrittr_1.5   
>   markdown_0.9    methods_3.5.2   mime_0.6        Rcpp_1.0.1     
>   rmarkdown_1.12  stats_3.5.2     stringi_1.4.3   stringr_1.4.0  
>   tinytex_0.12    tools_3.5.2     utils_3.5.2     xfun_0.6       
>   yaml_2.2.0
```